# Keeping divs and images separate entities

Tags: html, css, image

I have a layout on a products page for a bunch of images as i would like except for a few problems. My images and borders are one where as i would like the border (image containers) to be separate from the image. The text blocks that i have going across the images has some box shadow around them although nowhere have i said that i want box shadow, and finally, on some monitors, the images will lose their shape and just sit on top of each other. i want them to hold their shape until they absolutely must sit on top of each other because of screen size restrictions. I'm still new enough at coding so please try to be as clear (dumbed down) as possible. images and texts are only for illustration purposes so feel free to change them,

Thanks

```css
div.maintext {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
  width: 90%;
  font-weight: normal;
  font: ;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  padding: 25px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #888888;
  border-radius: 5px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.leftimg {
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
  height: auto;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 10%;
  `
}
h3 span {
  position: absolute;
  top: 60%;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  color: white;
  font: bold 35px/45px freestyle script, Sans-Serif;
  text-align: center;
  background: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  /* fallback color */
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
}
img[width="400"] {
  border: 3px solid #5F5F5F;
  border-radius: 3px;
  transition: .15s ease-out;
}
img[width="400"]:hover {
  opacity: 0.6;
  transition: opacity .15s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<div class="maintext">
  <div class="leftimg">
    <a href="Homepage.php">
      <img src="http://dummyimage.com/300" width="400" height="auto">
    </a>
    <a href="Homepage.php"><h3><span>Big American Burger</span></h3></a>
  </div>
  <div class="leftimg">
    <a href="Homepage.php">
      <img src="http://dummyimage.com/300" width="400" height="auto">
    </a>
    <a href="Homepage.php"><h3><span>Tasty Carvery</span></a>
    </h3>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="leftimg">
    <a href="Homepage.php">
      <img src="http://dummyimage.com/300" width="400" height="auto">
    </a>
    <a href="Homepage.php"><h3><span>Sausage and Chips</span></h3></a>
  </div>
  <div class="leftimg">
    <a href="Homepage.php">
      <img src="http://dummyimage.com/300" width="400" height="auto">
    </a>
    <a href="Homepage.php"><h3><span>Delicious Deserts</span></h3></a>
  </div>
  <div class="leftimg">
    <a href="Homepage.php">
      <img src="http://dummyimage.com/300" width="400" height="auto">
    </a>
    <a href="Homepage.php"><h3><span>Beautiful Carverys</span></h3></a>
  </div>
  <div class="leftimg">
    <a href="Homepage.php">
      <img src="http://dummyimage.com/300" width="400" height="auto">
    </a>
    <a href="Homepage.php"><h3><span>Tasty Carvery</span></h3></a>
  </div>
  <div class="leftimg">
    <a href="Homepage.php">
      <img src="http://dummyimage.com/300" width="400" height="auto">
    </a>
    <a href="Homepage.php"><h3><span>Sausage and Chips</span></h3></a>
  </div>
  <div class="leftimg">
    <a href="Homepage.php">
      <img src="http://dummyimage.com/300" width="400" height="auto">
    </a>
    <a href="Homepage.php"><h3><span>Delicious Deserts</span></h3></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: There is additional `</a>` after your `Tasty Carvery` that might be causing problem.

Comment: That doesnt make a difference, but thanks, i removed it.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have put a `div.maintext` a box shadow. You can use [boostrap](https://www.bootstrapcdn.com/) to make the page responsive easily and use [browser developer tools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_are_browser_developer_tools) to debug `js` and `css` bugs easily. A quick edit to [your code](https://jsfiddle.net/creativeRosh/3ogq6sf3/3/). This is a sample page, you can try [which i found](http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/beautiful-image-card-with-description) with a quick search.